# Detaching large ceramic tile without breaking it

Tags: tile, removal, ceramic-tile, demolition, thinset

Do I have any chance of lifting the tiles you see in the pictures without breaking them?

You can tell from the picture what I tried and how it went!

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to recover the tiles whole? If you want to reuse the tiles, you'll have to remove all the bits of mortar stuck on the back which is going to take a very long time...

Comment: If the tile was laid properly it should be nearly impossible to lift it. That said, it doesn't look like your tile was laid properly so you might have luck tapping with a very wide chisel.

Comment: @Matthew What did they do wrong?

Comment: The tiles should have been back-buttered. That ensures that it's well adhered to the tile. Then you get wet adhesive on the tile pressed into wet troweled adhesive on the substrate ensuring a good bond.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had (some) success using the following technique:

- using a utility knife or grout saw, remove as much grout as you can
- using a narrow *margin trowel* (see pic) with a hammer, carefully tap the trowel under the tile in as many places as you can. This breaks up the mortar somewhat. Do not use any leveraging type action until you have tapped the trowel under the tile around as much of the perimeter as possible
- **carefully** start using leverage with a **wide** margin trowel in various spots around the tile until it (hopefully) pops free in one piece

[image]